# Apps Script: how to copy hyperlink from a cell to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I need to copy this data from one sheet to another but with all the links active, because with this formula, copy just like a text.

I really don't know what do and what do I have to change to copy every data from the original sheet.

```js
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("ProyectStatus");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("ToCompleteProyect");

  var values = [
    [formS.getRange("D1").getValue(), formS.getRange("D2").getValue(), formS.getRange("D3").getValue(), formS.getRange("D4").getValue(), formS.getRange("D5").getValue(), formS.getRange("D6").getValue(), formS.getRange("D7").getValue(), formS.getRange("D8").getValue(), formS.getRange("D9").getValue(), formS.getRange("D10").getValue(), formS.getRange("D11").getValue(), formS.getRange("D12").getValue(), formS.getRange("D13").getValue(), formS.getRange("D14").getValue(), formS.getRange("D15").getValue(), formS.getRange("D16").getValue(), formS.getRange("D17").getValue(), formS.getRange("D18").getValue(), formS.getRange("D19").getValue(), formS.getRange("D20").getValue(), formS.getRange("D21").getValue(), formS.getRange("D22").getValue(), formS.getRange("D23").getValue(), formS.getRange("D24").getValue(), formS.getRange("D25").getValue(), formS.getRange("D26").getValue(), formS.getRange("D27").getValue(), formS.getRange("D28").getValue(), formS.getRange("D29").getValue(), formS.getRange("D30").getValue(), formS.getRange("D31").getValue(), formS.getRange("D32").getValue(), formS.getRange("D33").getValue(), formS.getRange("D34").getValue(), formS.getRange("D35").getValue(), formS.getRange("D36").getValue(), formS.getRange("D37").getValue(), formS.getRange("D38").getValue(), formS.getRange("D39").getValue(), formS.getRange("D40").getValue(), formS.getRange("D41").getValue(), formS.getRange("D42").getValue(), formS.getRange("D43").getValue(), formS.getRange("D44").getValue(), formS.getRange("D45").getValue(), formS.getRange("D46").getValue(), formS.getRange("D47").getValue(), formS.getRange("D48").getValue(), formS.getRange("D49").getValue(), formS.getRange("D50").getValue(), formS.getRange("D51").getValue(), formS.getRange("D52").getValue()]
  ];
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 52).setValues(values);

  ClearCell();
```

Comment: I can't help with your question, however I can tell you that instead of *repeatedly* calling `getRange()` you can provide an *actual* range to select: `formS.getRange('D1:D52')`. I'd suggest reading the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)

Answer (score 2):

Complete project with Submit, Search and Update buttons:

```js
function ClearCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("ProyectStatus");
    var RangeToClear = ["D1:D52"];
    for (var i = 0; i < RangeToClear.length; i++) {
        formS.getRange(RangeToClear[i]).clearContent();
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function SubmitData() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("ProyectStatus");
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("ToCompleteProyect");
    var lastRow = dataS.getLastRow() + 1
    formS.getRange("D1:D52").copyTo(dataS.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 52), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)
    dataS.getRange(lastRow, 1).clearDataValidations()
    ClearCell();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Search() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("ProyectStatus");
    var str = formS.getRange("D1").getValue();
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("ToCompleteProyect")
    var values = dataS.getDataRange();
    Logger.log(values.getLastRow())
    for (var i = 0; i < values.getLastRow(); i++) {
        var row = dataS.getRange(i + 1, 1).getValue();
        if (row == str) {
            dataS.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, 51).copyTo(formS.getRange("D2:D52"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)

        }
    }

}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Update() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("ProyectStatus");
    var str = formS.getRange("D1").getValue();
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("ToCompleteProyect")
    var values = dataS.getDataRange();
    Logger.log(values.getLastRow())
    for (var i = 0; i < values.getLastRow(); i++) {
        var row = dataS.getRange(i + 1, 1).getValue();
        if (row == str) {
            formS.getRange("D2:D52").copyTo(dataS.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, 51), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)
            ClearCell();
        }
    }
}
```

One simple way to do it is just to copy-paste but not only the values but the cells transposed as one would do with the Copy and Paste Special. It's indeed a much simpler code and it seems to me that does the trick, you just need this line:

> formS.getRange("D1:D52").copyTo(dataS.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 52), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true) ---> this last TRUE value is the one which transposes the data

And the full function:

```
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("ProyectStatus");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("ToCompleteProyect");
  var lastRow = dataS.getLastRow() + 1
  formS.getRange("D1:D52").copyTo(dataS.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 52), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)
  ClearCell();
}
```

---

Old Answer: If the links is always in the same column/s of the last row, you can then pass them through this second function. I took myself the liberty also of suggesting a way of simplifying grabbing the values of the form ;)

```
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("ProyectStatus");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("ToCompleteProyect");

  var values = formS.getRange("D1:D52").getValues() //Here I took the entire range
  values = [values.map(function(n){return n[0]})] // and turn that column into a row
  
  var lastRow = dataS.getLastRow() + 1
  dataS.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 52).setValues(values);

  linkCellContents(dataS.getRange(lastRow, 10, 1, 1)) // assuming you need to make a link the value in column number 10 (J)... repeat this line with each column you need to convert

  ClearCell();
}

function linkCellContents(range) {
 var value = range.getValue()
 var richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText(value)
   .setLinkUrl(value)
   .build();
 range.setRichTextValue(richValue);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your time!! 
It did not work properly. What I am trying to do is copy information in column D2:D52 in the sheet "ProyectStatus" which has a Hyperlink to the originals documents. 
When it is copied, the Hyperlink disappears. 

Thanks again for your time and assistance. I will read what you told me to.

Comment: When I try this "linkCellContents(dataS.getRange(lastRow, 10, 1, 1)) for each column, it is copied like a link but does not copy the hyperlink in the sheet "ProyectStatus"

Comment: So each original cell is linked to its original source?? and you want to copy that link?
For example: D1 says "134" and its linked to "www.google.com.....", D2 says "343" and its linked to "www.wikipedia.com.....", and so on??

Comment: Yes Martin, the original cells are linked to Google Drives Hyperlink. I have several documents there linked.

I realized that you were the one who helped me out with this, so thanks a lot for your time and help!!

Comment: Hello Martin, Do you think you could help me out with this?? Thank you so much for your time !! @Martín

Comment: Hello @Gaston --> Look at the new Edit

Comment: It Works!! When I push the save Button, it copies the exact data, Hyperlink, and even the format. 
Is it too much if I ask you the same for my Update Button? Please, if it is, I am still so thankful for your help!!

Comment: Hello! I'm glad! What does your Update button do? What have you done and expect to happen?

Comment: I have a save button, a search button, an update button, and a clear button. What I do is first submit the data, save it, and sometimes I have to search or update data of my project, so when a search all the data I already submit, I have to update the existing data with the new one. Do I make myself clear?  
Right now, the update button, does the same as the save button did before you fix my problem, it updates the data as plain information only.

Comment: Could you share a copy of your spreadsheet?? It can be empty, or with a couple of imaginary rows, just to understand how you locate the rows to be searched/updated?

Comment: Probably you should just need to change in this line of code lastRow with the variable you had found since you have a Search button already working. formS.getRange("D1:D52").copyTo(dataS.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 52), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true)

Comment: Yes, that's why I told you to change it, he -> I've edited again with the new code, I've also modified the Search button or you would lose there the format and hyperlinks. Buena suerte!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Love u men!!! Valoro mucho tu tiempo, gracias en serio

Comment: I'm glad that it worked  That's what we're here for! (Consider setting this question as answered )

Comment: Painful to see how much work went into this answer and not accepted nor upvoted (until now).